# past simple or present perfect for an action connected to the future

Tags: past-tense

> My friends told me that they **planned** to see me next Sunday before going back home. I told  them that it was very nice but completely forgot to add that I won't be there next Sunday,  the day they **planned** to see me.

Is past simple a good choice for "plan"  or would it be better to use present perfect for the second "planned"  because they may change  the date.

Comment: Actually, I would use the past continuous "they were planning"  in both cases. The simple past is OK, but I wouldn't use the perfect. (Comment rather than answer because I can't immediately think how to explain this choice).

Comment: The simple past is fine in both instances. It doesn't matter that they might change the date, they still planned to see you Sunday.

Answer (score -1):

What you are dealing with here is reported speech.
The assumption is that your friends told you this:

> We are planning to see you next Sunday before going back home.

Therefore, if we report that speech the way you did, that becomes:

> My friends told me that they were planning to see me next Sunday
>   before going back home.

(Tenses shift from present continuous to past continuous. If you do not know how reported speech works you can find a pretty good explanation [here](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/reported-speech.html).)

Now to review your second sentence:

> I told them that it was very nice but completely forgot to add that I won't be there next Sunday the day they planned to see me.

You should never use "planned". Because they didn't "plan". You would never say "I plan to see you.", instead you'd say "I am planning to see you".
The best tense to use in this scenario would be past perfect continuous, because they had been planning **before** you told them that it was very nice, and past perfect is used to express that something happened before something. If you don't quite understand that you can read [this](http://www.englishtenses.com/tenses/past_perfect_continuous).

I don't know how you came to the conclusion that you should use present perfect. Present perfect is not used to express probability, as you suggested.

Comment: You would never say "I plan to see you"? I think that you are in the minority. .https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+plan+to+see%2CI+am+planning+to+see&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20plan%20to%20see%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20am%20planning%20to%20see%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Well that is weird. I can't find an explanation to that.@JavaLatte

Comment: Shouldn't there be a comma after “... be there next Sunday”? Also, @JavaLatte, present progressive tense is usually used with future plans, appointments, and similar. The simple tense here sounds more formal.

Comment: @user2684291: One uses present continuous to **imply** future plans: "I am meeting her tomorrow". When you use the verb **plan**, it is an **explicit**  plan, so it is redundant to additionally imply future plans by using present continuous. I agree that it is grammatically correct but, as the NGram shows, it is less common than using present simple.